# Photoshop Javascript script: Rename file and saveAs

Tags: javascript, photoshop, file-rename

Im new to using JS with photoshop and have some trouble. What I want to do is to get rid of the word "*Online*" in the file name of the current document and then save a JPG with new file name in a different folder.

With the help of the adobe reference I came up with the following script:

```
//Path where the final jpg should be saved
var JPGquality = 12;
var docPath="C:\Users\user\Desktop\test";
var docName='';

docName = activeDocument.name;

//Set new file name by replacing "_Online_" with "_"

var NewName = docName.replace("_Online_", "_");



var saveFile = new File(docPath+'/'+NewName+ '.jpg');


//Save JPG 

function SaveJPEG(saveFile, jpegQuality) {

jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
jpgSaveOptions.quality = jpegQuality; //1-12
activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, jpgSaveOptions, true,Extension.LOWERCASE);
}
```

The Script runs through but therewithout errors but nothing happens. It would be very helpful if someone could tell me what Ive done wrong. Hope someone helps me figuring out how to fix this ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use forward slashes in your `docPath`:

```
var docPath="C:/Users/user/Desktop/test";
```

`\t` (tab) and `\u` (beginning of a Unicode sequence) have special meanings in JS strings.

Or you can escape them, of course:

```
var docPath="C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test";
```

Comment: ohhh forgot to change it after copying from the explorer. But thanks now Im one step closer to working script ;-)

Comment: In that case I have no idea what might be the cause. I haven't yet installed Photoshop on this machine, but I've written a similar script at some point. Take a look and see if it helps in any way: https://github.com/igstan/sublime-text-icons/blob/master/create-iconsets.jsx

Comment: Also, put a `try/catch` around the whole script with an `alert(e)` inside the `catch` block, although I think they had a debugger for these scripts...

Comment: Okay I rewrote the script from scratch with the slashes and your tips in mind and somehow it works now ;-) This time I just put the `jpgSaveOption` and `saveAs` outside of a function. The script now is pretty basic. Big thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
function saveAsJPG() {

    jpgFile = new File(outputFolder + "/" + _CardFileName + ".jpg");
    jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
    jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
    jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
    jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
    jpgSaveOptions.quality = 12;
    docRef.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to write paths in javascript for photoshop automation is '/c/users/user/'  That works on both mac and windows and you don't need to escape the backslashes